# How to create a public hangout using hangouts API

Tags: google-hangouts, hangouts-api

I'm trying to create an application which has 2 types of users:

1. Customer
2. Store owner

   - Customer should be able to hangout with the store owner without having logged in to Google.
   - Store owner should be able to switch cameras to display his products.

I'm thinking of creating a Google Hangout Application which will be at the Store owner's end. When the owner arrives at the store, he should be able to start a public hangout so that customers with that link can directly talk with the owner.

Is there any way to do this? Is there any other approach for this problem?
Do I really need Google Hangout Application (and make it public)

Suggestions are kindly welcomed. Thank you